# Classifying of Equilibrium points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to know , which  equilibrium points the following system has:

$$x'=x^2-2xy-1+a$$
$$ y'=x-y+1$$
$a \in (\frac{-1}{2019}, \frac{1}{2019})$

When I consider $ y'=0 \Rightarrow  x=y-1 $
When I put that in the first equation, I get $ y^2+2y-2xy+a=0$

This leads to nothing. How do I have to do it ?

Comment: Thank you, Below I tried to classify the critical points. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, but I want to find out, wether this points are stable or not?

Comment: I did this already. Look at the bottom of this side, please.

Comment: I calculated it. Can't you see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the equation
$$(y+1)^2-2y(y+1)-1+a=0$$
expanding

$$y^2+2y+1-2y^2-2y-1+a=0$$ so $$y=\pm \sqrt{a}$$ if $$a\geq 0$$

Comment: Thank you:)I forgot to substitue x.

Comment: I get $y_{1,2}=2 \pm \sqrt{a+4}$ and then $x_{1,2}=  3 \pm \sqrt{a+4}$. These are my points, aren't they?

Comment: Ok I forgot the - :( When i consider the jaccobian $J(\sqrt{a}-1, \sqrt{a})= \begin{pmatrix} -2 & -2(\sqrt{a}-1)  \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: tr(J)<0 and$ det(J)=-3 +2\sqrt{a} >0 $. The last condtion isn't going to work because of the definition of a, so this point is unstable, isn't it?